# Translation Golf LI - Yours in distress, Alan

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

With all the recent events across stacks I don't know if people are still in the mood for a good game of Translation Golf, but I have been keeping some records (and the idea) to publish this edition one day and I don't want to leave it forever forgotten at the bottom of my *to-do* list. I'd rather see it published and not answered than unpublished.

If this is your first time with Translation Golf, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

And here's the text <sup>1</sup> of Edition LI:

> I've now got myself into the kind of trouble that I have always considered to be quite a possibility for me, though I have usually rated it at about 10:1 against. I shall shortly be pleading guilty to a charge of sexual offences with a young man. The story of how it all came to be found out is a long and fascinating one, which I shall have to make into a short story one day, but haven't the time to tell you now. No doubt I shall emerge from it all a different man, but quite who I've not found out.

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here is a potential translation which uses 403 characters:

> Me he metido en el tipo de problema que siempre consideré bastante probable para mi, aunque normalmente lo había evaluado como de una posibilidad entre diez. En breve me declararé culpable de un cargo de ofensa sexual con un hombre joven. La historia de cómo llegó a descubrirse es larga y fascinante, y deberé contarla en una versión más corta otro día, pero ahora no tengo tiempo de explicártela. No hay duda de que saldré de ella como un hombre distinto, pero quién exactamente todavía no lo sé.

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

---

<sup>1</sup> About the chosen text:

Alan Turing was a human being of exceptional intelligence — a mathematical genius — and worked as one of the leading code-breakers during World War II. He is also considered to be the "father of modern computing" thanks to his pioneering work in the field of computer science.

His work during the World War II, breaking the Enigma code, shortened the war in Europe by as many as two to four years. At a conservative estimate, each year of the fighting in Europe brought on average about seven million deaths, so the significance of Turing's contribution can be roughly quantified in terms of the number of additional lives that might have been lost if he had not achieved what he did.

If U-boat Enigma had not been broken, and the war had continued for another two to three years, a further 14 to 21 million people might have been killed (Source to some references for those claims: [Alan Turing: The codebreaker who saved 'millions of lives'](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-18419691)).

In 1952, he was charged with gross indecency after admitting to a sexual relationship with another man, and as a result was told to choose either imprisonment or chemical castration as punishment. He chose the latter. Alan Turing was found dead on June 8th, 1954, a day after taking his own life. He was aged just 41.

Turing wrote the letter used in this post (the whole letter can be seen and read in the picture below) in 1952 to his friend and fellow mathematician, Norman Routledge, shortly before pleading guilty.

[image: YoursInDistress]

Comment: Qué historia tan increíble y triste a la vez, la de Alan Turing, y cuánto le debemos el mundo en general y  los informáticos en particular...

Comment: Por cierto, gracias por el texto, una historia interesante (con sus matices tristes) de una gran mente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 115 Caracteres

> Heme en mi lío único, con su riesgo viable. A aceptar que tomé a un chico. El quid inusual y largo, lo sabrás, mas hoy no hay tiempo. Y cambiaré ignaro

- El 10 por ciento lo tomo como algo viable.
- [Tomar](https://dle.rae.es/tomar) con la acepción 23
- Con quid me refiero a la esencia de la historia y como se descubre la misma
- Turing cambia ignaro, pues no sabrá de que forma cambiará ni en que se convertirá.

Como extra y pidiendo excusas al Op por trastocar casi el 60 % del texto y a Turing por como trato su historia...

### 148 - 10% = 134 caracteres

> Vaya con este rollo
>   Por salir con un pollo
>   Y como era probable
>   A confesarme culpable
>   Una historia interesante
>   Que sabrás en su instante
>   He de salir diferente
>   Mas no lo capta mi mente

Me lleva... que este no es poema...

Comment: No se si es tu primera vez participando -- yo deje de participar por un tiempo -- pero si es asi, que bien.  Divertido, no? // Hay muchas cosas aqui, es una entrada creadora.  Pero: El lío no era del todo remoto, chequea el texto original.  Es un poco contradictorio, y creo que hay que captar eso. "Notable" hmm, hay que ver que piensan los demas, para mi no capta *fascinating*.  La ultima frase no me convence, al igual que la entrada de wimi.  Este texto es de veras divertido, por las muchas ambivalencias.  Queremos ser sucintos -- pero creo que hay que conservar las complejidades.

Comment: Siento haberme olvidado por completo del Translation golf!! Estoy teniendo una semana loca. Con 115 (y nadie ha puesto pegas al texto) creo que eres el ganador.

Answer (score 5):

#### <strike>204</strike> 125 caracteres

> Opciones: 1 entre 10... mas pasó lo temido. Diré que soy culpable de indecencia por un joven. Una gran historia que ya te contaré y que me cambiará, mas no sé cómo.

Me encanta la versatilidad de *[ya](https://dle.rae.es/ya)*, sirve tanto para pasado como para presente y futuro:

> 1. adv. En tiempo u ocasión pasados. *Ya hemos hablado de esto.*
>   2. adv. Inmediatamente, ahora mismo. *Aumento de salarios, ya.*
>   4. adv. En tiempo u ocasión futuros. *Ya nos veremos.*

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think the nutty laws in that period were about offenses against decency, i.e. society, not against the other participant.  In other words it was completely different from a sex abuse case.  So "**a** un joven" doesn't seem right to me -- but again, I'm not an expert.

Comment: I like how you kill two birds with one stone with "gran." // I don't care for the last bit -- I think everyone is collapsing the last part too much.

Comment: @aparente001 you're right, "a un joven" does not sound right given the context. I'll try to ammend that. // That was the purpose of "gran", precisely. :-)

Answer (score 5):

#### 178

I am posting this prior to reading the hidden translation in the question, and also prior to reading Charlie's.  I don't want to allow myself to be influenced by the other treatments.  Please check it for faithfulness to the original.

> El apuro siempre posible pero improbable (10:1) ya llegó. Diré *mea culpa* a cargos sexuales con un joven.  Corto el tiempo para contar la revelación; pero publicada, fascinará.  Al fin seré otro, sin duda, pero justo quién, aún no sé.

Answer (score 3):

#### 120 caracteres

> Lo improbable (10:1) pasó: confesaré un delito sexual con un joven. Es fascinante cómo me pillaron: algún día lo publico. Esto me cambiará, mas no sé cómo.

Comment: Todo me parece fiel y super creador, menos "contra", que cambie a "con", y la ultima frase, que para mi es nada fiel al texto original.  Por ahora voto en contra pero si compones la ultima frase con gusto cambio mi voto.

Comment: @aparente001 he cambiado la última frase. Yo creo que "I shall emerge from it all a different man" es en esencia "Esto me cambiará", y que cosas como "al fin" o "sin duda" se pueden deducir del contexto y no están en todas las otras respuestas. O es otro el problema con la última frase?

Comment: I guess.  I don't know how to explain why but I don't feel it. The idea "resurgirá un hombre nuevo" seems faithful; I'm not getting that from yours. // You could shave off two letters with *algún día lo publico* (I got rid of the future tense).

Comment: @aparente001 gracias por la sugerencia. 
 Curiosamente, parece que todas las demás respuestas (excepto la tuya) han optado por escribir la última frase casi exactamente igual que yo...

Comment: Well, Charlie changed his. He used to have "resurgirá un hombre nuevo" which for me was quite faithful to the original idea in that section.  And I did let VeAqui know about the problem I saw with the last sentence.  I think I've been consistent.

Comment: @aparente001 yes, you have been consistent, I did not say that you have not :) Actually, the word "new" does not appear in the original text, which is why I also removed it from my version.